# retrieve variable with ajax load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve variable meja into barang.php, but it always saying 'Notice: Undefined index: meja in C:\xampp\htdocs\goeladjawa\barang.php on line 3'....

**this is the javascript**

```
var htmlobjek;
var menu;
var meja;
var harga;
var jumlah;
var stok;

$(function(){
    $("#barang").load("barang.php");
    $("#tambah").click(function(){
if(jumlah > stok) {
    alert("Stok tidak terpenuhi");
    $("#jumlah").focus();
    exit();
    } else if(jumlah < 1) {
    alert("Jumlah pesan tidak boleh 0");
    $("#jumlah").focus();
    exit();}

    harga=$("#harga").val();
    stok=$("#stok").val();
    jumlah=$("#jumlah").val();
    meja=$("#meja").val();

    $("#status").html("sedang diproses. . .");
    $("#loading").show();

    $.ajax({
    url: "tambah.php",
    data: {menu:menu,meja:meja,harga:harga,jumlah:jumlah},
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg){
    if(msg=='sukses'){
        $("#status").html("Berhasil disimpan");
        }
    else{
        $("#status").html("ERROR");
        }
    $("#barang").load("barang.php","meja");
        }
    });
    });
});
```

**this is barang.php**

```
<?php 
 include"db/koneksi.php";
 $meja=$_GET['meja'];
 $brg=mysql_query("select * from pemesanan where no_meja='$meja' ")or die (mysql_error());

 echo "<thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Barang</td>
            <td>Jumlah Beli</td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td>Tools</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>";
 $total=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select sum(subtotal) as total from pemesanan where no_meja='$meja'"));
 while($r=mysql_fetch_array($brg)){
    echo "<tr>

            <td>$r[nama_menu]</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='jum' value='$r[jumlah]' class='span2'></td>
            <td>$r[subtotal]</td>
            <td><a href='pk.php?op=hapus&kode=$r[nama_menu]' id='hapus'>Hapus</a></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>
    <td colspan='3'>Total</td>
    <td colspan='4'>$total[total]</td>
</tr>";
?>
```

the html

```
<select name="meja" id="meja">
<option>--Pilih Meja--</option>
```

this is what I want, when we click 'tambah' then it will be appeared on table based on 'pilih meja'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3PU.jpg

Comment: try add $.ajax({
    url: "barang.php",type: "GET", in ajax post function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load function seems wrong. Check the sample below.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "barang.php", { meja: '<pass value>' }, function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: yes, but the table won't appear when im using $.get() ... it something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3PU.jpg